# Postgres SQL Select words frequency where first leter is not @ or #

Tags: sql, postgresql, hql, word-frequency

I try to Select words frequency where first leter is not @ or # but not working, any advices ? Thanks

```
SELECT word, count(*)
FROM ( 
  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(tc.text, '\s') as word
  FROM WORDS_TABLE as tc
) t
WHERE word NOT LIKE '%@'OR NOT LIKE '#%'
GROUP BY word
```

What would this query look like in hql?

Comment: Shouldn'it be `WHERE word NOT LIKE '@%'` ?

Comment: right , now is working thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Use `AND` in where clause instead of `OR` .Also in second clause field name is missing.

```
SELECT word, count(*)
    FROM ( 
      SELECT regexp_split_to_table(tc.text, '\s') as word
      FROM WORDS_TABLE as tc
    ) t
    WHERE word NOT LIKE '@%' AND word NOT LIKE '#%'
    GROUP BY word
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this logic:

```
WHERE word NOT LIKE '%@' OR NOT LIKE '#%'
```

Both the pattern and the `OR` is incorrect.  You might find it easier to write this using a regular expression:

```
WHERE word ~ '^[^@#]'
```

That is, the word does not start with either of those characters.